# CakePHP - How to change default plugin router config

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new in CakePHP. I have added a plugin in my Cake app, and its name is "Admin". Now it's working fine, when I use "localhost/admin/..." to access it. My question is, I want to hide /admin from users, for instance, I want to use "localhost/console/..." to replace the default route config. I googled a lot, never got an answer. So how to change default route config of plugin in CakePHP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to be applicable to all the plugin controllers/actions, you need to be a little more verbose. Try:

```
Router::connect('/console/:controller/:action/*', array('plugin'=>'admin'));
```

But if that's what you want, you're better off just renaming your "Admin" plugin to "Console".  Re-routing all the plugin controllers and actions will make debugging not very fun. :)